# com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 missing when running "perform eclipse" in roo

Tags: java, maven-2, spring-roo

When I run "perform eclipse" in Roo I get:

```
roo> perform eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bugzter
[INFO]    task-segment: [eclipse:clean, eclipse:eclipse]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [eclipse:clean {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Deleting file: .project
[INFO] Deleting file: .classpath
[INFO] Deleting file: .wtpmodules
[INFO] Deleting file: .component
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.wst.common.component
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
[INFO] Deleting file: org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.prefs
[INFO] Preparing eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
      1) org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0
      2) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.snapshot (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot),
  snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 28 20:57:52 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/298M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tried downloaded the tools-1.4.2.jar and run mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file but it doesn't solve the problem.

Running ubuntu 10.04 and maven 2.2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Repoint your system environment parameter JAVA_HOME to JDK (1.5+) directory instead of JRE.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spring Source Roo and missing com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2](http://raflab.gazelle.net/roller/rnoolabs/entry/spring_source_roo_and_missing):

> If you are trying to get the latest
>   version of SpringSource ROO working,
>   with an x64 Java JDK, such as the
>   latest JDK 1.6 update 20, there is
>   unfortunately a missing tools.jar from
>   the default `lib\` directory of the JDK
>   (tut tut tut Sun/Oracle). This will
>   prevent Roo from working and therefore
>   prevent Maven compilation. You would
>   probably see an error similar to this:
>
> ```
> Error message: Missing:
> ----------
> 1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2
>
> Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
>
> Then, install it using the command:
> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
>
> Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
> mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
>
> ----------
> 1 required artifact is missing.
> ```
>
> To correct this error, install an
>   additional x86 JDK, repoint the
>   JAVA_HOME and the PATH to the new JDK
>   and restart the mvn process

Comment: I wonder if it'd be worth checking 1.6 update 21 to see if they added it.  Probably not.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: It's certainly worth checking but I'm too lazy to install a 64-bit JDK on my 32-bit platform.

Comment: I'll have to remember when I'm at home... I have a 64-bit Java 6u21 JDK installed there; albeit for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

i thought i had java_home set to jdk, but i guess in slackware both jre and jdk get installed in same folder. having both installed caused this problem. i uninstalled both, and reinstalled jdk (to be safe) and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependecy in pom.xml file.

in the `<systemPath>` property you have to write your JDK lib path.

```
    <dependency>  
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId> 
           <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_30/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue and fixed int the following way.

Go to lib directory of JDK installed path in command prompt. Execute the below command to install to install tools.jar. $mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=sun.jdk -DartifactId=tools -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.6 -Dfile=tools.jar

http://parameshk.blogspot.in