# maven giving error with spring roo

Tags: java, maven, spring-roo

Initially i had x64 bit java sdk and x64 bit STS installed.

But then i see this [spring reference to problem](http://raflab.gazelle.net/roller/rnoolabs/entry/spring_source_roo_and_missing)

2)for second dependency **[i tried this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1111)** but same problem

Then i again installed x86 sdk and x86 STS but problem is still there. what should i do . i have chnaged the JAVA_HOME TO NEW sdk.

the error is below

DO i need to add something in PATH variable as well

```
Missing:
----------
1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0
    2) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release),
  codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
  spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release),
  snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
  JBoss Repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases)



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Missing:
----------
1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0
    2) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release),
  codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
  spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release),
  snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
  JBoss Repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases)


    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:711)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkProjectLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1205)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1038)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:643)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
----------
1) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun -DartifactId=tools -Dversion=1.4.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency: 
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0
    2) com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  spring-maven-milestone (http://maven.springframework.org/milestone),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  spring-roo-repository (http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release),
  codehaus.org (http://repository.codehaus.org),
  spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release),
  snapshots (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org),
  JBoss Repo (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases)


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:360)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.ensurePluginContainerIsComplete(DefaultPluginManager.java:835)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:647)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 08 02:10:36 CST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/42M
[INFO] ----------------------------
```

Comment: sibling issue, may be, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356716/com-suntoolsjar1-4-2-missing-when-running-perform-eclipse-in-roo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are several ways of resolving this problems. However, what you can do is defining a profile that defines a dependency to tools.jar:

```
...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
```

Comment: i am new to this dependency thing , where can i paste the above code , i mean in which file

Comment: I tried that but same result . i have seen that tools.jar is in borth x32 and x64 sdk . i think they have fixed that but i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both x64 and x86 version of JDK installed, one possibility is that STS is still using the x64 version.